# std::filesystem::copy invalid permission error on mounted fs

Tags: c++, copy, c++14

I'm using the function in C++ standard library [filesystem::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy) to copy a file from a path on a mounted folder to another in the same mounted filesystem (my OS is Redhat 7).

When i execute it as a sudo user the function copy the file as expected. But when i execute it on a user without user permission i get the error

> filesystem error: cannot copy: Operation not permitted

I initially supposed it was a Unix permission problem, but the permission on the file i'm trying to copy are correct

> -rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root

If i try to copy the file with **cp** or **mv** system function i don't have any problem and the file is copied as expected.

It seems that **filesystem::copy** invokes a different system function from **cp**, but which one? Why the former work only as a sudo user, when the file has the correct reading/write permission? Could it be a problem with symlinking?

Comment: *but which one?* -- Isn't the source code available to `filesystem::copy` for you to see what is being done?